# Error with fst library python

Tags: python

I run Ubuntu and I followed all the instructions found here [link](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/www.cs.sfu.ca/~anoop/teaching/CMPT-413-Spring-2014/pyfst-intro.ipynb) ..

Where I try to test the fst library I get this error

```
>>> import fst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fst/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fst._fst import EPSILON, EPSILON_ID, SymbolTable,\
ImportError: libfst.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually installed openfst? What does `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libfst*` say?

Comment: Also, your question says "Erro with ftp library". `openfst` is not an FTP library. Is the question title wrong, or the library in the question?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       924 Feb 15 17:05 /usr/local/lib/libfst.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       960 Feb 15 17:05 /usr/local/lib/libfstscript.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        21 Feb 15 17:05 /usr/local/lib/libfstscript.so -> libfstscript.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        21 Feb 15 17:05 /usr/local/lib/libfstscript.so.1 -> libfstscript.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 102374564 Feb 15 17:05 /usr/local/lib/libfstscript.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        15 Feb 15 17:05 /usr/local/lib/libfst.so -> libfst.so.1.0.0

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        15 Feb 15 17:05 /usr/local/lib/libfst.so.1 -> libfst.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6192644 Feb 15 17:05 /usr/local/lib/libfst.so.1.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the loader isn't looking for libraries in `/usr/local/lib`. Add that directory to your loader config in `/etc/ld.so.conf*` and run `ldconfig`.

Comment: There may be a good reason it isn't looking there, like a 32-bit-vs.-64-bit reason, in which case this would be a bad idea…

Comment: @abarnert: If that's why then the loader will know the difference.

Comment: I am not very familiar with ubuntu so I am sure if I understood it right. 

So I open the file /etc/ld.so.conf* and added the line include /usr/local/lib

correct??

Comment: @user2617287: It won't have that name specifically. There is a file that has nothing in place of the wildcard, but there may also be a directory that contains text files with directory information. Prefer putting a file in that directory over adding a line to the file.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: If his platform is, e.g., keeping 32-bit and 64-bit libraries separate, and he's installed a 64-bit library into a 32-bit path, the right answer is not to hack things up to make that work, but to install it to the right place in the first place.

Comment: Well, I found a file in that directory with this name which already had this line include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf   So I added this line include /usr/local/lib ..  And it Worked!!